# Problemas con el atributo translate="no" en HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags, setattribute

compañeros.
Tengo el siguiente problema en mi sitio. He escrito el atributo en algunos botones y etiquetas `span` dentro de mi sitio web con el atributo `translate="no"`, pero al momento de testearlo me lo traduce todo igual.
He probado con los navegadores **google chrome**, **Vivaldi**, **Edge** y **Opera** pero en todos lo traduce igual. Añado parte de mi código:

`

```
<div class="cont-text c-t home-text">
  <h3>WELCOME TO&nbsp;<span translate="no">MY PAGE</span>.</h3>
  <br /><br />
  <h3>THE FUTURE...</h3>
</div>
```

`

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: **¿Hay alguna otra manera de poder hacer que algunos elementos como botones y etiquetas span no se traduzcan en ningún navegador?**

A todos los elementos que no quería que se traduzcan les he puesto el siguiente atributo:

`translate="no"`.

Comment: No parece que este demasiado soportado [ese atributo](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_translate.asp)... Si te fijas en el enlace no hay ningún navegador que parezca darle soporte... a saber ni porque existe, je  [Aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/translate) más info

Comment: Si usas el traductor de Google, prueba con esto: **`<span class="notranslate">MY PAGE</span>`**

Comment: Otra posibilidad es poner el texto dentro de una etiqueta `code`, porque [según esto](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-translate-flag#stickyness), ese texto no será traducido, luego, por CSS puedes invalidar el formato para ese texto. Algo así en el HTML: **`<code class="nocode">MY PAGE</code>`** y en el . css: **`.nocode { code: unset; }`** Quizá esto sea más estándar, porque por lógica, el código nunca se traduce.

Comment: Eso es raro. A mí me funciona bien. No me traduce donde está `translate="no"` ya sea div, span o parrafo

Comment: @masterguru para la compatibilidad consulta siempre el sitio Can I Use. [`translate` es soportado por casi todos los navegadores](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_global_attributes_translate). No quiero hablar mal de nadie, pero w3schools [tiene a veces contenido obsoleto, y en el pasado enseñaba malas prácticas de programación](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280484/5587982), no sé si con el tiempo han corregido esas cosas.

Comment: @masterguru [aquí una historia interesante sobre w3schools](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4977/186960) por si no la conoces. Debido a lo narrado en esa respuesta, ellos se corrigieron con el tiempo en algunas cosas, aunque siguen dando información desactualizada, como el enlace de tu comentario, donde dicen que `translate` no es soportado por ningún navegador, lo cual es falso. La conclusión es que es mejor usar la doc oficial para los enlaces en nuestras respuestas/comentarios, o sitios específicos para la compatibilidad, porque se dedican a eso.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si te fijas en mi comentario, verás que también he puesto un enlace en la palabra **Aquí** al final del mismo que apunta a la información actualizada en la doc oficial.

Comment: @A.Cedano Acabo de leer el enlace que me has proporcionado, y sí, algo sabía del tema de hace tiempo (que no está bien considerado entre muchos desarrolladores), pero a nivel personal, gracias a ellos me he podido introducir y entender algunas cosas básicas, pues cuando buscas por google cosas de programación estan siempre muy bien posicionados, y aunque es más que probable que esten desactualizados, me sirven de referencia básica para luego indagar mejor en otros lugares, conforme voy conociendo mejor los lugares oficiales y otros de referencia extendida.

Answer (score 0):

La etiqueta `translate`, aparte de ser relativamente nueva, depende de otras cosas, como el servicio de traducción que se utilizará. Ambas cosas dificultan un estándar a la hora de escribir el código.

No obstante, [según lo dicho en W3.org](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-translate-flag#stickyness), tienes al menos dos posibilidades:

### 1. Si usas traducción de Google o Microsoft

Ambos admiten la clase `notranslate`, de modo que podrías resolverlo así:

```
<span class="notranslate">MY PAGE</span>
```

### 2. El contenido etiquetado con `code` no se traduce

Esto parece ser más estándar, porque el código nunca debería traducirse. De modo que puedes poner el contenido dentro de `code` y luego quitar el formato con `unset`.

Sería una opción interesante, mientras `translate` se estandariza o surgen librerías al respecto.

Por ejemplo:

```css
.nocode {
    code: unset;
}
```

```html
<class="nocode" code>MY PAGE</code>
<br /><code>SÍ CODE</code>
```